# ParametricPlot - Problem with ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I am unhappy with the following mapping:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re@Sin[u + I v], Im@Sin[u + I v]},
 {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#3] &),
 ImagePadding -> 20,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

because of the distinct coloring of its left and right part.
I found a certain fix with this:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re@Sin[u + I v], Im@Sin[u + I v]},
 {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Green, Yellow, Blue, LightBlue, Blue, 
      Yellow, Green, Red}, #3] &),
 ImagePadding -> 20,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

But I really would prefer to use one of the inbuilt gradients to
color my figure according to its polygon size or "mesh density".

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Something like `(Hue[#3] &)`?

Comment: `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Abs[2 #3 - 1]] &)`

Comment: Mr. Coward: I don't particularly care, but could you give a reason for downvoting my question?

Comment: If you don't care then why call them a coward and ask for a reason?

Comment: @RahulNarain - Maybe I'm naive - but what is "witch-hunting for downvoters" ? I spent an hour to find a solution myself (to no avail), and received excellent answers so far.

Comment: I meant the tendency of some people to start accusing everyone who comments "Are you the downvoter?" "Are *you* the downvoter?". Often if someone reveals that they downvoted, the OP then goes and downvotes or leaves negative comments on their other unrelated posts. I'm not suggesting you would do that, I'm simply saying that one should not be expected to reveal one's votes, and asking whether one has downvoted should be considered an intrusive question.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks, understood. (relatively new here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
ParametricPlot[
  {Re@Sin[u + I v], Im@Sin[u + I v]},
  {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][If[#3 < .5, 1 - #3, #3]] &), 
  ImagePadding -> 20, 
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: "small fishes" - but somehow I wasn't able to catch them :)

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot[
 {Re@Sin[u + I v], Im@Sin[u + I v]},
 {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Abs[2 #3/Pi]] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ImagePadding -> 20,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotPoints -> 30,
 Mesh -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[
 {Re@Sin[u + I v], Im@Sin[u + I v]},
 {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1 - Abs[2 #4/Pi]] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ImagePadding -> 20,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotPoints -> 30,
 Mesh -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[
 {Re@Sin[u + I v], Im@Sin[u + I v]},
 {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
     1 - ((1 - Abs[2 #3/Pi])^2 + Abs[2 #4/Pi]^2)] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ImagePadding -> 20,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotPoints -> 30,
 Mesh -> Automatic]
```

[image]